# Is there criteria on when to choose ODDS ratio or Prevalence Ratio?

Tags: odds-ratio, prevalence

Am stack between using Prevalence Ratio and ODDS Ratio. Is there any statistical backing on choosing one over the other? If yes, what could that be and would one generate the PR in R?

Comment: If you are using methods such as logistic regression, then this is based on the logarithm of the odds

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The prevalence ratio is simply the proportion of the total population which has the the condition $PR=\frac{\text{number with condition}}{\text{total number}}$ $=\frac{\text{number with condition}}{\text{number with condition}+\text{number without condition}}$.

The odds of having the condition is then $O=\frac{PR}{1-PR}$ $=\frac{\text{number with condition}}{\text{number without condition}}$, and you can say $PR=\frac{O}{1+O}$.

An odds ratio would be the ratio of two odds, such as the odds for one group divided by the odds for another group